# MYSql 5.7- user is not able to change his own password having select access

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL 5.7.38 hosted on AWS RDS, and created one user with select-only access. That user is not able to change his password.

Is it a feature of MySQL 5.7.38 or am I doing wrong something?

The user is trying to change his password from PHPMyAdmin UI.

Comment: How is this user trying to reset their password? What command are they using?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html *Any client who connects to the server using a nonanonymous account can change the password for that account. (In particular, you can change your own password.)* and *Setting the password for yourself (for a nonanonymous account with no FOR clause) requires no special privileges. When the read_only system variable is enabled, SET PASSWORD requires the SUPER privilege in addition to any other required privileges.*

Comment: The user is trying to change his password from PHPMyAdmin UI.